# Find generating function of $ a_n=2a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2}+4n-1 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have to find generating function of $ a_n=2a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2}+4n-1 $ where $a_0=1$ and $a_1=3$. I'm currently stuck at the form:

$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n = 1 + 3x +2x\sum_{n=2}^\infty(a_{n-1}x^{n-1})-3x^2\sum_{n=2}^\infty(a_{n-2}x^{n-2})+\sum_{n=2}^\infty((4n-1)x^{n})$

I have no idea how to go further.

Answer (score 0):

Let's restart from beginning.
 We have
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  a_{\,n}  = 0\quad \left| {\;n < 0} \right. \hfill \cr 
  a_{\,0}  = 1 \hfill \cr 
  a_{\,1}  = 3 \hfill \cr 
  a_{\,n}  = 2a_{\,n - 1}  - 3a_{\,n - 2}  + 4n - 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

The best approach is to adjust the recurrence as to accomodate 
the initial values. We shall do in this way
$$
\eqalign{
  & a_{\,0}  = 1 = 2a_{\,0 - 1}  - 3a_{\,0 - 2}  + 4 \cdot 0 - 1 =  - 1\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad a_{\,n}  = 2a_{\,n - 1}  - 3a_{\,n - 2}  + 4n - 1 + 2\left[ {0 = n} \right]  \cr 
  & a_{\,1}  = 3 = 2a_{\,0}  - 3a_{\,1 - 2}  + 4 \cdot 1 - 1 + 2\left[ {0 = 1} \right] = 5\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  & a_{\,n}  = 2a_{\,n - 1}  - 3a_{\,n - 2}  + 4n - 1 + 2\left[ {0 = n} \right] - 2\left[ {1 = n} \right] \cr} 
$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$$
\left[ P \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {P = TRUE}  \\
   0 & {P = FALSE}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$

So we get a recurrence which is valid for all $0 \le n$.
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  a_{\,n}  = 0\quad \left| {\;n < 0} \right. \hfill \cr 
  a_{\,n}  = 2a_{\,n - 1}  - 3a_{\,n - 2}  + 4n - 1 + 2\left[ {0 = n} \right] - 2\left[ {1 = n} \right] \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
or better
$$
a_{\,n}  = 2\left[ {1 \le n} \right]a_{\,n - 1}  - 3\left[ {2 \le n} \right]a_{\,n - 2}  + 4n - 1 + 2\left[ {0 = n} \right]
 - 2\left[ {1 = n} \right]\quad \left| {\;0 \le n} \right.
$$

Now we can multiply by $x^n$ and sum
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_{\,n} x^{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left[ {1 \le n} \right]a_{\,n - 1} x^{\,n} }  - 3\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left[ {2 \le n} \right]a_{\,n - 2} x^{\,n} }  +   \cr 
  &  + 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {nx^{\,n} }  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {1x^{\,n} }  + 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left[ {0 = n} \right]x^{\,n} }  - 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left[ {1 = n} \right]x^{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {a_{\,n - 1} x^{\,n} }  - 3\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {a_{\,n - 2} x^{\,n} }  +   \cr 
  &  + 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {nx^{\,n} }  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {1x^{\,n} }  + 2x^{\,0}  - 2x^{\,1}  =   \cr 
  &  = 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_{\,n} x^{\,n + 1} }  - 3\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_{\,n} x^{\,n + 2} }
  + 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {nx^{\,n} }  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {x^{\,n} }  + 2 - 2x =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {2x - 3x^{\,2} } \right)\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_{\,n} x^{\,n} }  + 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {nx^{\,n} }  - {1 \over {1 - x}} + 2 - 2x \cr} 
$$

And the term with $nx^n$ becomes
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {nx^{\,n} }  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {nx^{\,n} }  = x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {nx^{\,n - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = x{d \over {dx}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {x^{\,n} }  = {x \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,2} }} \cr} 
$$

Finally
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(x) = \left( {2x - 3x^{\,2} } \right)f(x) + 4{x \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,2} }} - {1 \over {1 - x}} + 2 - 2x  \cr 
  & f(x) = {{5x - 1} \over {\left( {1 - 2x + 3x^{\,2} } \right)\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,2} }} + {{\left( {1 - x} \right)} \over {\left( {1 - 2x + 3x^{\,2} } \right)}} \cr} 
$$

Comment: And what about the first part? How do i deal with sums starting from 1 or 2, instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Calling $A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$ we have

$$
(a_k-2a_{k-1}+3a_{k-2})x^k = (4n-1)x^k
$$

and

$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k x^k = A(x) - a_0-a_1 x\\
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_{k-1} x^k = x(A(x)-a_0)\\
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a_{k-2} x^k = x^2A(x)
$$

and also

$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k x^k = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-1-x\\
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}-1-x
$$

and after some algebraic operations

$$
A(x) = \frac{1}{1-2x+3x^2}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{1-x}-a_0+a_1 x\right)
$$